# Trying to clearTimout after a setTimeout in a modal without Jquery

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and I am trying to clear a set timeout on a modal after a specific number of seconds.

```
setTimeout(showModal, 3000);
  function showModal(){
    var m = document.getElementById("modal-demo");
    m.style.display = "block"
}
```

I have the modal appearing on the webpage after 3 seconds but I cant seem to make it disappear after a certain number of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` methods to not work this way.

If you create a timer with `setTimeout` you can only use `clearTimeout()` before the code executes to prevent it from executing. Once it executes clearing it has no effect.

What you need to do instead is set another timeout to hide your modal:

```html
<div id="modal-demo">Mock Modal</div>

<script>

setTimeout(showModal, 3000);

function showModal(){
    var m = document.getElementById("modal-demo");
    m.style.display = "block";
    window.setTimeout(hideModal,3000);
} 
function hideModal() 
{
    var m = document.getElementById("modal-demo");
    m.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I see you are just getting acquainted. Please take a moment to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for the link I accepted your answer and voted on it. Unfortunately I still don not have enough reputation to give a vote but I still appreciate it!